# Proving ~~(~~S -> S) in coq with only basic tactics

Tags: logic, coq

Is it possible to solve `~~(~~S -> S)` in coq? I know you cant perform double negation elimination in intuitionistic logic but is this possible as you simply proving double negation on `(~~S -> S)` as opposed to `~~S ->` S itself?

This is only using basic tactics and not lemmas from prelude or standard library etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is provable. Step by step, you do it like this:

```
Goal forall S : Prop, ~ ~ (~ ~ S -> S).
Proof.
unfold not.
intros S H1.
apply H1.
intro H2.
apply False_rect.
apply H2.
intro H3.
apply H1.
intro H4.
apply H3.
Defined.
```

Or you can use `tauto`, which is a decision procedure for intuitionistic propositional calculus.

```
Goal forall S : Prop, ~ ~ (~ ~ S -> S). Proof. tauto. Defined.
```